# Changing width of h1 when img is hovered over

Tags: css, hover, width, image

I'm trying to expand the width of my h1 tag when you hover over the img, however I cannot seem to get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/xJ4dc/

Thanks.

Comment: Okay thanks! How would you recommend I go about achieving the effect then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
img:hover + h1 {
    width:100%;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xJ4dc/4/)**.

This rule says that whenever you hover over an image, change the width of all adjacent sibling `<h1>` elements to 100%.

Comment: Ah thank you! I don't know how I've got this far without knowing this.

Comment: Actually its only for the adjacent h1 sibling

Answer (score 1):

The Selector has to select the element for it to apply the rule.
In your fiddle `img:hover` has no desendant `h1` therefore nothing happens.
In this case, since `h1` is the next sibling of `img:hover` you can use the [+](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) selector

```
img:hover + h1
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/xJ4dc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to understand what `img:hover h1` says:

> upon all tags named `img` on `:hover` all child elements tags named `h1`

you would need to use the plus sign `img:hover + h1` to work.

But I would suggest do is http://jsfiddle.net/xJ4dc/5/

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://www.real-whitby.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/donkey.jpg" />
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    </li>
</ul>
​
```

and then:

```css
li img {
    width: 100px;
}

li h1 {
    display: none;
}

li img:hover + h1 {
    display: block;
}
​
```

Note that I would use `display:none;` and then `display:block` to hide and show the heading.

Answer (score -1):

The selector `img:hover h1` means "any h1 element that is a descendant of an img being hovered over".  The problem is your `h1` element isn't a descendant of your `img` tag, it's a sibling.  You can change to using the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) to get the desired effect:

```
img:hover + h1 {
    width:300px;
}
```

​